# Select menu using two arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

How can I create a dropdown using two arrays, one for values and one for text?

```
    var values = [10, 25, 50, 100];
    var text = ['ten', 'twenty-five', 'fifty', 'hundred'];
```

So that I would then get the following select:

```
<select>
     <option value="10">ten</option>
     <option value="25">twenty-five</option>
     <option value="50">fifty</option>
     <option value="100">hundred</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you mean how could you accomplish this programmatically using Angular?

Comment: Yes, ideally in the mark-up. I'm assuming, I would need `ng-repeat` or `ng-options`.

Comment: So you cannot modify the controller code at all?

Comment: Use ng-options, do not use ng-repeat

Answer (score 4):

You can do some what like this but thats quite irrelevant logic of yours

```
<select>
     <option ng-repeat="t in text" value="{{values[$index]}}">{{t}}</option>
</select>
```

You can change it to some thing like this also, make one associative array or object like

```
$scope.values = {"10":"ten", "25":"twenty-five","50":"fifty", "100":"hundred"};
```

**Demo**

```js
app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testctrl',function($scope){
$scope.values = {"10":"ten", "25":"twenty-five","50":"fifty", "100":"hundred"};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="testctrl" ng-app="test">
  
<select>
     <option ng-repeat="(key,val) in values "  value="{{key}}">{{val}}</option>
</select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I realize it would make more sense to have an array of objects which would have the value and text. However, I'm stuck with these two arrays.

Comment: you can try it and will get through it after optimizing your logic :)

Comment: you know you are repeating the whole `select` and not the `options` right ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli thanks, nah i dont wana do that ;)